# Find the endpoint of a vector with quaternion

Tags: python, vector, 3d, quaternions

If I have got the startpoint and the length of a vector (not zero) and also has the quaternion of the point, how can I get the end point? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What does *"quaternion of the point"* mean? Quaternions describe a rotation but points do not.

Comment: I am not pretty sure because it is shown on a laser measurement tool, it shows the start point, length and the quaternion. Maybe it is the quaternion of the vector.

Comment: So you have a magnitude and a quaternion. I imagine what the tool means is "take the reference vector multiplied by this magnitude and rotate it by the quaternion", where "the reference vector" is... well, a reference vector, probably `(1, 0, 0)` although cannot tell for sure. So if the magnitude is `m` and the quaternion is `(w, x, y, z)`, you probably just need to take the vector `(m, 0, 0)` and rotate it by that quaternion. See [this answer from Math SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/535223) that explains how to do that.

Comment: I guess this measurement tool treats the position at the time of booting as the origin of coordinates, and the tool to target as a vector. The position, length and quaternion of the vector are shown on the screen. And I want to find the endpoint of the vector, which is the position of the target.